# Openlayers vector feature coordinates are not transforming,

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon, coordinate-system, coordinates, vector

I have a OpenLayers vector with a single feature [0]. It's coordinates are in the map projection (EPSG:3413) and I want them in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) decimal degrees. I have the following code which executes with no errors.

```
    // Transform the polygon to WGS84 (EPSG:4326)
        polybound.features[0].geometry.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3413"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));

        // Get the extent/vertices of the polygon drawn
        var polyBounds = polybound.features[0].geometry.getVertices(); alert(polyBounds);
        var polyExt = polybound.features[0].geometry.getBounds(); alert(polyExt);
```

However both the alerts show the untransformed coordinates.

Eg:

alert(polyBounds);

```
POINT(-2486558.28125 -1947299.71875),POINT(-4121511.40625 -1737690.34375),POINT(-3555566.09375 -2722854.40625)
```

alert(polyExt);

```
-4121511.40625,-2722854.40625,-2486558.28125,-1737690.34375
```

How do I get the vector feature coordinates to transform correctly?

Comment: Are you using the Proj4js library? Have you referred to the proper projection in Proj4 format?

Comment: @Davdatta Tengshe I'm not using the Proj4js library, rather whatever is build into OpenLayers. The (new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3413")) works because thats what my map frame is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the OpenLayer Docs for [OpenLayers.Projection](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Projection-js.html).  The docs state the following:

> By default, OpenLayers ships with the ability to transform coordinates
>   between geographic (EPSG:4326) and web or spherical mercator
>   (EPSG:900913 et al.) coordinate reference systems....
>
> Additional transforms may be added by using the proj4js library.  If
>   the proj4js library is included, the transform method will work
>   between any two coordinate reference systems with proj4js definitions.

So you need to refer to the Proj4JS library and have your projection file for EPSG:3413.

You should read this [User Guide](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/wiki/UserGuide). You can download the library from here: [Downloads](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/wiki/Download). You will also need the file for your projection in Proj4 format. You can download that from here: [Spatial reference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3413/)

Comment: Thank you. Got it working now. I'll update my question with the actual solution later today.

Answer (score 0):

@kpurdon, there is no problem with your code but you have to know that transforming is not overwriting to existed feature. so try the following code:

```
alert(polybound.features[0].geometry.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3413"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")));
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: How can I write the transformed feature to a new feature so I can access the vertices and bounds in the transformed projection?

Comment: Also, the alert you gave still printed the un-transformed coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as same was my case:

```
var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3413");

var polygon= polybound.feature.geometry;
    //alert(polygon);
    var bounds=polygon.getBounds();
    var poly = polygon.transform(
            mercator,geographic 
        );
alert(poly);
```

Hope will works!

Comment: I get the same un-transformed results using this method.